# Startup receiver not working in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, receiver

To be more clear I'm refering to receiver thar reacts to android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

I've successfully tested that receiver working in a physical device with API 23.

But, on the other hand, I haven't been able to even run it on emulator in, for now, version 22 and 24, it doesn't even seem like it reaches the OnReceive of the receiver, the receiver is just ignored.

Is it some limitation of the emulator that doesn't allow to start these types of receivers? If that is the case, could I at least assume that even if in emulator isn't working it would fire on a physical device? (For testing purposes I could start the receiver from somewhere else, so it wouldn't mind much as long as that condition applies).

It could also be that the receiver is declared is such a way that it just doesn't work on this versions, this is how I declared the receiver:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.applications.-----.--------.NoCoverageAndSpaceFullReceiver"
        android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I don't think there's nothing there that would avoid the receiver from working, but just in case, I'm putting it.

PD: I've already set the emulator to do a cold boot, so the problem is not in that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not coldbooting the emulator, you should probably also add the following action as well.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check,